# A way or software to convert or export an audio file (aiff or wav) in a vector graphic format (eps, ai)?

Tags: macos, software-rec, osx-leopard, adobe-illustrator, vector-graphics

I am looking for a way to read an audio file and convert it to a vector graphic format, which I can use for example for Illustrator? I am working on the Mac OSX platform (10.5.8).

Comment: What do you expect to be the output from this process? I'm finding it hard to conceive of converting **sound** to **pictures**.

Comment: @ChrisF: It's not *impossible*, it's just never done as a vector graphic format (e.g. spectrograph).

Comment: @Ignacio - Of course! The vector part threw me.

Comment: @ChrisF: The idea came to me, because I need a high resolution waveform picture in a digital format for a print publication and they asked me if I would have my waveform (which is just a screenshot of audacity) as a vector graphic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it will output vector graphics but you might want to check out something like
[Oscilloscope and Spectrum Analyzer Software](http://www.picotech.com/picoscope-oscilloscope-software.html).

If this doesn't have anything built-in (which is unlikely) then you might want to look at [raster to vector conversion software](http://www.raster-vector.com/) (for example). This type of software works well with line drawings (scanned engineering drawings for example) and your waveform might be suitable too.

Comment: thanks I found Delineate for OSX. I am still looking for a proper way to plot it. I found LabPlot but it is for KDE, which is for linux I suppose..

Comment: Here is another solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826701/plot-audio-data-in-gnuplot